# How can I remove duplicates from objects of object

Tags: javascript, duplicates, javascript-objects

I have an object of objects and some of these objects have similar attributes (eg. `tempId`) and their `key` is gotten from the object's `id` attribute, how can I remove duplicates (of objects with similar `tempId`) leaving just the one with the `id` key set. For example, if I have this object below:

```
{
 '' => { id: '', tempId: 'abcde', name: 'king', age: 5 },
 'aSaJsk' => { id: aSaJsk, tempId: 'abcde', name: 'king', age: 5 }
}
```

I would like to return:

```
{
 'aSaJsk' => { id: aSaJsk, name: 'king', age: 5 }
}
```

At the moment I have tried using this but it returns the first duplicate to appear in the object.

```js
function removeDuplicates(myObj) {
  const obj = keyBy(uniqBy(Object.values(myObj), "tempId"), "id");
  const messages = Object.assign({}, obj);
  return messages;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `Set()`. ***The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.*** Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for.

```js
const mainObject = {
            '': {
                id: '',
                tempId: 'abcde',
                name: 'king',
                age: 5
            },
            'aSaJsk': {
                id: 'aSaJsk',
                tempId: 'abcde',
                name: 'king',
                age: 5
            }
        };


Object.keys(mainObject).forEach(key => {
        if ('tempId' in mainObject[key] && !mainObject[key].id){
                delete mainObject[key];
        }
});
```

This code will remove all the objects that have `tempId` but not `id`, I'm not sure how you would like to deal with your problem if there are more than two objects having the same `tempId` but only one of them have no `id`. If you want the others except for the one with no id then this answer would serve you too.

I hope this helped you a little and feel free to clarify your problem more to give you a more compatible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `reduce` and checking if any duplicate value exists in the reducer accumulator. If there is one then skip it, otherwise push it.

Here I use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for turn object into an array and also [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) for turn array into object.

```js
const data = {
 'sdkad': { id: 'sdkad', tempId: 'abcde', name: 'king', age: 5 },
 'aSaJsk': { id: 'aSaJsk', tempId: 'abcde', name: 'king', age: 5 },
 '4dkj': { id: '4dkj', tempId: 'cde', name: 'king', age: 5 },
};


const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).reduce((res, [key, val]) => {
  if (!res.find(v => v[1].tempId === val.tempId)) {
     res.push([key, val]); 
  }
  return res;
}, []));

console.log(res);
```